# Can't cast array of Object to array of generic type when generic type implements interface

Tags: java

I'm implementing a Quicksort class in Java. For sorting to work, the items that are to be sorted need to be comparable, for example by implementing the `Comparable` interface. However, implementing `Comparable` gives me problems when casting at runtime in a method that returns array slices:

```
public class QuickSorter<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    ...

    private T[] sliceOfArray(T[] arr, int start, int end) {
        Object[] slice = new Object[end - start];

        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            slice[i] = arr[i];
        }

        return (T[]) slice; // Throws exception at runtime.
    }
}
```

The exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Comparable;
    at com.sortingalgos.QuickSorter.sliceOfArray(QuickSorter.java:55)
    at com.sortingalgos.QuickSorter.sort(QuickSorter.java:11)
    at com.sortingalgos.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:11)
```

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple fix is to change this line

```
    Object[] slice = new Object[end - start];
```

to

```
    Comparable[] slice = new Comparable[end - start];
```

The business of casting to `T[]` is a hack. It doesn't actually change tbe type of the array. You don't want to be passing it around pretending that it really is correctly typed. It may be clearer to use `Object[]` (or `Comparable[]`) or just plain old `List<T>`.

Comment: But if I cast it and no error is thrown at runtime, can I not be sure that the array is of type `T[]`?

Comment: @Sahand No, and you will get a warning. `-Xlint:all` should show that. It's unfortunate that that flag is often not used when compiling. In the original code for example the array is absolutely of type `Object[]`.

Comment: Okay. And by "It may be clearer to use `Object[]`", do you mean I should have the method return an `Object[]` instead?

Comment: @Sahand Yes. And quite possibly `arr` should be `Object[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't even do the following:

```
        Object[] a = new Object[] {1,3,4,5};
        Integer[] b = (Integer[])a;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
```

This is because there is no guarantee that `Object[] a` doesn't really look like the following:

```
      Object[] a = new Object[]{1,3,4,5.7}
```

Which clearly is not an array of Integer.  But you could do this.

```
        Object[] a = new Integer[] {1,3,4,5};
        Integer[] b = (Integer[])a;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that an array of `Object` isn't an array of `Comparable`. You need the `slice` array to have the same element type as the `arr` array. You can achieve this by changing

```java
Object[] slice = new Object[end - start];
```

to

```java
T[] slice = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(arr.class.getComponentType(), end - start);
```

In other words, use reflection to determine at runtime the element type, and create slice arrays of the same type.

Using reflection is likely to be less performant, however. For an in-place sort algorithm like QuickSort, you shouldn't need to create any new arrays at all, you could just use the input array. (Or clone it, if you aren't allowed to modify the input.)

Comment: You're right, I should re-implement the sorter so that it uses only one array and works with indexes instead of array slices.